# how to get always array from JMS Serializer?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

```
/**
 * This function is used to get all Stopes.
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  resource=true,
 *  section="Stop",
 *  description="This function is used to get all Stopes",
 *  statusCodes={
 *         200="Returned when successful",
 *         404="Returned when the Stop is not found"
 *     }
 * )
 *
 * @return mixed
 * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"main"})
 */
public function cgetAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $stopes = $em->getRepository(self::ENTITY)->findAll();

    return $stopes;
}
```

I use JMS Serializer for rest.

This is my code from Rest controller. Its return json or array (server, localhost). How to get ALWAYS array response ?

Comment: This is known limitation. Never have been sure why the author was too reluctant to include pull requests but there have been some forks of `JMSSerializer` implementing just that...

Answer (score 1):

I`m found answer

```
 /**
 * This function is used to get all Stopes.
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  resource=true,
 *  section="Stop",
 *  description="This function is used to get all Stopes",
 *  statusCodes={
 *         200="Returned when successful",
 *         404="Returned when the Stop is not found"
 *     }
 * )
 *
 * @return mixed
 * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"main"})
 */
public function cgetAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $stopes = $em->getRepository(self::ENTITY)->findAll();


    return array_values($stopes);
}
```

Comment: Great! Just beware of the behavior when you have `Doctrine`'s proxy classes as members ;) Also, I've just got around to find this discussion that I consulted few months ago: https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/pull/20